# Android : load an imageview from a Parsefile

Tags: android, image, parse-platform, imageview

I'm trying to find a ParseObject by " objectId ", then retrieve the image " ImageFile " and then Load it to the imageview, it doesn't work and i'm getting the USER String, can you help me out with this, it works when i use another query like : query.find()

```
      ParseImageView mealImage = (ParseImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query1 = ParseQuery.getQuery("Annonces");


    query1.getInBackground("ux3Af0cwEx", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
      public void done(ParseObject Annonces, ParseException e) {


             photoFile = (ParseFile) Annonces.get("ImageFile");
             text1.setText((CharSequence) Annonces.get("USER"));

      }
    });
    mealImage.setParseFile(photoFile);
    mealImage.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {

        }
    });

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The code for displaying image in imageview:

```
ParseFile image = (ParseFile) userData.getParseFile("user_image");
```

then call following function.

```
loadImages( photoFile, mealImage);
```

---

```
private void loadImages(ParseFile thumbnail, final ImageView img) {

    if (thumbnail != null) {
        thumbnail.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                    img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                } else {
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.menu);  
    }
}// load image
```

Comment: This works great. Any idea about loading a thumbnail in custom width/height from a ParseFile object?

Comment: compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"  use picaso for image download put this in gradle and use this code  String chatImageFile = message.getParseFile("image").getUrl();


Picasso.with(this) .load(chatImageFile)         .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder) // optional         .error(R.drawable.ic_error_fallback)      // optional         .resize(250, 200)                        // optional         .rotate(90)                             // optional         .into(imageView); if you find this useful plse accept as ans

Comment: Remove that rotate(90)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Picasso** or **Glide** for image loading and don't want to change the image loading logic, you can **extract image url from ParseFile** and load it in background.
Like:

```
ParseFile thumbnail = parseObject.getParseFile("image");
if(thumbnail != null) {
    String imageUrl = thumbnail.getUrl();
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
}
```

No need to load **thumbnail** ParseFile data separately.

Comment: This is not a good solution as you are going to reload the image.